# How can I highlight a node in a treeview when selecting it?

Tags: c#, winforms

The problem is that inside OnDrawNode I'm using specific background and alternative colors already :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class AdvancedTreeView : TreeView
{
    private Bitmap openedIcon, closedIcon;
    private List<TreeNode> rootNodes = new List<TreeNode>();

    public AdvancedTreeView()
    {
        DrawMode = TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawText;
        ShowLines = false;
        AlternateBackColor = BackColor;
        ArrowColor = SystemColors.WindowText;
        this.AllowDrop = true;  
    }

    public Color AlternateBackColor { get; set; }
    public Color ArrowColor { get; set; }

    protected override void OnDrawNode(DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {
        Color backColor = (GetTopNodeIndex(e.Node) & 1) == 0 ? BackColor : AlternateBackColor;
        using (Brush b = new SolidBrush(backColor))
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, new Rectangle(0, e.Bounds.Top, ClientSize.Width, e.Bounds.Height));
        }

        // icon
        if (e.Node.Nodes.Count > 0)
        {
            Image icon = GetIcon(e.Node.IsExpanded);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(icon, e.Bounds.Left - icon.Width - 3, e.Bounds.Top);
        }

        // text (due to OwnerDrawText mode, indenting of e.Bounds will be correct)
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Node.Text, Font, e.Bounds, ForeColor);

        // indicate selection (if not by backColor):
        if ((e.State & TreeNodeStates.Selected) != 0)
            ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle(e.Graphics, e.Bounds);

    }
```

And since it's keep doing calling OnDrawNode all the time it will never do the part inside the OnAfterSelect :

```
protected override void OnAfterSelect(TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Node.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
```

Once I click on a node and selecting it, It will also go to the OnDrawNode and will color the node/s in it's original colors again.

I want to keep the code in the OnDrawNode but also to be able to highlight the selected node/s.

EDIT : This is what I have tried so far :

Inside the OnDrawNode :

```
Color backColor = (GetTopNodeIndex(e.Node) & 1) == 0 ? BackColor : AlternateBackColor;
        if ((e.State & TreeNodeStates.Selected) != 0)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, e.Bounds);
        }
        else
        {
            using (Brush b = new SolidBrush(backColor))
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, new Rectangle(0, e.Bounds.Top, ClientSize.Width, e.Bounds.Height));
            }
        }
```

But there is two problem with this :

1. In the two screenshots when it's on Node10 it looks like fine but when it's on Node9 you can it's coloring the whole line. And I wanted to highlight only the text "New Node 10" ... "New Node 9" and not the whole line.
2. When selecting a node on the red line triangle there is something small in white color. It wasn't like that before changing the code in the OnDrawNode.

[image: Selected Node 10]

And the second screenshot :

[image: Selected Node 9]

This is the full code of the TreeView control :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class AdvancedTreeView : TreeView
{
    private Bitmap openedIcon, closedIcon;
    private List<TreeNode> rootNodes = new List<TreeNode>();

    public AdvancedTreeView()
    {
        DrawMode = TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawText;
        ShowLines = false;
        AlternateBackColor = BackColor;
        ArrowColor = SystemColors.WindowText;
        this.AllowDrop = true;
    }

    public Color AlternateBackColor { get; set; }
    public Color ArrowColor { get; set; }

    protected override void OnDrawNode(DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {
        Color backColor = (GetTopNodeIndex(e.Node) & 1) == 0 ? BackColor : AlternateBackColor;
        if ((e.State & TreeNodeStates.Selected) != 0)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, e.Bounds);
        }
        else
        {
            using (Brush b = new SolidBrush(backColor))
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, new Rectangle(0, e.Bounds.Top, ClientSize.Width, e.Bounds.Height));
            }
        }

        // icon
        if (e.Node.Nodes.Count > 0)
        {
            Image icon = GetIcon(e.Node.IsExpanded);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(icon, e.Bounds.Left - icon.Width - 3, e.Bounds.Top);
        }

        // text (due to OwnerDrawText mode, indenting of e.Bounds will be correct)
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Node.Text, Font, e.Bounds, ForeColor);

        // indicate selection (if not by backColor):
        if ((e.State & TreeNodeStates.Selected) != 0)
            ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle(e.Graphics, e.Bounds);
    }

    protected override void OnItemDrag(ItemDragEventArgs e)
    {
        // Move the dragged node when the left mouse button is used.
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            DoDragDrop(e.Item, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }

        // Copy the dragged node when the right mouse button is used.
        else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            DoDragDrop(e.Item, DragDropEffects.Copy);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDragOver(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        // Retrieve the client coordinates of the mouse position.
        Point targetPoint = this.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));

        // Select the node at the mouse position.
        this.SelectedNode = this.GetNodeAt(targetPoint);
    }

    protected override void OnDragDrop(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Point targetPoint = PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        TreeNode targetNode = GetNodeAt(targetPoint);
        TreeNode draggedNode = (TreeNode)e.Data.GetData(typeof(TreeNode));
        if (draggedNode == null || targetNode == null || draggedNode.Level != targetNode.Level)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            TreeNode parentNode = targetNode;
            if (!draggedNode.Equals(targetNode) && targetNode != null)
            {
                bool canDrop = true;
                while (canDrop && (parentNode != null))
                {
                    canDrop = !Object.ReferenceEquals(draggedNode, parentNode);
                    parentNode = parentNode.Parent;
                }
                if (canDrop)
                {
                    TreeNode treeNode = draggedNode.Parent;
                    if (treeNode != null)
                    {
                        int index = draggedNode.Index;
                        draggedNode.Remove();
                        treeNode.Nodes.Insert(targetNode.Index, draggedNode);
                        targetNode.Remove();
                        treeNode.Nodes.Insert(index, targetNode);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int draggedindex = draggedNode.Index;
                        int targetindex = targetNode.Index;
                        draggedNode.Remove();
                        targetNode.Remove();
                        this.Nodes.Insert(targetindex, draggedNode);
                        this.Nodes.Insert(draggedindex, targetNode);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        SelectedNode = draggedNode;
    }

    private int GetTopNodeIndex(TreeNode node)
    {
        while (node.Parent != null)
            node = node.Parent;

        return Nodes.IndexOf(node);
    }

    // Determine whether one node is a parent 
    // or ancestor of a second node.
    private bool ContainsNode(TreeNode node1, TreeNode node2)
    {
        // Check the parent node of the second node.
        if (node2.Parent == null) return false;
        if (node2.Parent.Equals(node1)) return true;

        // If the parent node is not null or equal to the first node, 
        // call the ContainsNode method recursively using the parent of 
        // the second node.
        return ContainsNode(node1, node2.Parent);
    }

    private Image GetIcon(bool nodeIsExpanded)
    {
        if (openedIcon == null)
            InitIcons();
        return nodeIsExpanded ? openedIcon : closedIcon;
    }

    private void InitIcons()
    {
        openedIcon = new Bitmap(16, 16);
        closedIcon = new Bitmap(16, 16);
        using (Brush b = new SolidBrush(ArrowColor))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(openedIcon))
                g.FillPolygon(b, new[] { new Point(0, 0), new Point(15, 0), new Point(8, 15), });
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(closedIcon))
                g.FillPolygon(b, new[] { new Point(0, 0), new Point(15, 8), new Point(0, 15), });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check to see if the node is highlighted like you do with the Focus Rectangle:

```
Color backColor = (GetTopNodeIndex(e.Node) & 1) == 0 ? BackColor : AlternateBackColor;
using (Brush b = new SolidBrush(backColor))
{
  e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, new Rectangle(0, e.Bounds.Top, ClientSize.Width, e.Bounds.Height));
}
if ((e.State & TreeNodeStates.Selected) != 0) {
  e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, e.Bounds);
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question to be more specific with what I wanted and with two problems I see when highlighting in green like in your answer. I want to color only the text part of the node/s not the whole line. And I'm not sure what is the small white color on the red triangle that show now after changing the highlighting code in the OnDrawNode.

Comment: @MuhamadAbutShtil Then just call the highlight coloring after the backcolor is filled.  I updated the post.